# Populate PHP Array With Results of MySqlI Query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a php array that holds all fields and rows of the mysql query that is executed.  I have tried the below syntax, but when I do a echo nothing is displayed.

````php
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("server", "user", "pass", "db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM testTable LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


foreach($array as $index => $value){
    echo "<p>\$index: {$index}; \$value: {$value[0]}</p>";
   var_export($value);
}

mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($con);
?>```

If I change the foreach loop and use $result instead of $array - it will print on screen 

    $index: 0; $value:

    $index: 1; $value:

And I want the actual elements (or is values the right word) of the array.
````

Comment: What is `$array`? Surely you meant `foreach($result as $index => $value){`? You're not doing anything with the result of the query.

Comment: if I use $result it prints on screen $index: 0; $value:

$index: 1; $value: - I want the actual values

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Comment: @cotton - are saying I'll have to iterate each of the fields returned from the select statement in the print statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, following on from your edit and what Obsidian said. Your loop is now correct you just need to update your echo now. Try this and let me know the result:

```
foreach($result as $index => $value){
    echo "<p>\$index: " . $index . "; \$value: " . $value . "</p>";
    var_export($value);
}
```

Okay, all good. The $value is just an array. Try this instead:

```
foreach($result as $index => $value){
    echo "<p>\$index: " . $index . "; \$value: "; print_r($value);  echo "</p>";
    var_export($value);
}
```

Comment: Hi - this outputs the below ```php
$index: 0; $value: Array

array ( 'salesman' => 'Bob Jones', 'NumberOfSales' => '1', 'MonthSales' => '0.000000', 'LastMOnth' => '0.000000', 'TwoMonths' => '0.000000', )
?>``` so it seems the var_export works but the echo does not

Comment: @HotTomales I've updated my answer. Check if that works.

Comment: YES!  That is exactly what I was after.  Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. Happy to help :-)